# Am I allowed to wear a towel as a belt/scarf outside an Eiruv on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Many Mikvas do not provide towels for attendees, and require that people who go bring their own towels. If there is no Eiruv, one cannot carry it in a normal way, so many people "wear" it as a belt/scarf (in the winter).

Is this allowed?

---

Always CYLOR

Comment: Generalization: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22091

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 301:34 and Mishna Berura SK 129](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=167)
- [Shulchan Aruch Harav 301:37](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/301a/37)
- [Rambam Mishna Torah Shabbos 19:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=12&perek=19&halocha=19&hilite=) and [19:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=1551)

Basically, you can take a handkerchief and wear it as a belt or scarf, as long as you tie the ends together. If it is big enough that it covers your head and majority of your body (like a big tallit) you can wear it that way without having to tie it down.

see [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=906) and [here](http://www.webshas.org/shabbos/melachos/hotzaah/moving/clothing.htm) as well.

Comment: If This were true, you would be obligated to put Tzizit on the Towel... which nobody does...  So while this might be ok for women, it would seem to not be allowed for men.

Comment: @avi - Why is wearing tzitzit even required if they would go to the mikveh at night time?

Comment: @avi, If both ends (= all 4 corners) of the towel are hanging in front of you (as apposed to draping one end behind your back) then I doesn't need tzitzis. (just like a collared shirt!)

Comment: @Danield Not everyone agrees to that.

Comment: Does this logic render a sweater tied around the neck or waist fine as well?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it?  If you wear it, you're fine.  It would be better if it was dry, so there was no possibility of ringing out any moisture (water).

PLEASE feel free to EDIT to improve answer quality.

Comment: The issue is the "carrying" issue. Is it considered "Carrying" vs. "Wearing". I usually don't wear a towel as a belt.

Comment: If you are "wearing" it, then it needs Tzizit....