# Neckties on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

What is the halachic status of neckties on shabbat? I have heard that because they are not true garments, they cannot be worn in an area without an eruv. What is the source, if any, for this, and is it permissible?

Comment: ????? Never heard of such a thing?????

Comment: I have heard the argument that, because they're worn for adornment and not warmth, they can be worn outside on _Shabas_ only so long as they remain an adornment: if dirty, they cannot. But I heard that as an argument only and not as a ruling.

Comment: It is possible the sources quoted in this answer would apply here as well: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10875/603 -- since the tie does not cover his head and majority of his body, he can wear it if it is tied in a knot.